# Indexing character to integer in tuple and using this for dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples, such as:

```
corp = [('h','somename'), 
        ('h','someothername'),
        ('a','awholeothername'),
        ('a','name again'),
       ]
```

I wish to create a dictionary where the first index, h or a, is mapped to an integer, in the way of

```
for x,y in corp:
    if x == 'h':
       x = 1
    x = 0
```

But this does not seem to work, as we can not do item assigning in Python. After having mapped all of the 0'th indexes to integers...

what I tried:

```
dicts = {'nationality': {} , 'name': {}}
for x,y in data:
    dicts['nationality'] == x
    dicts['name'] == y
```

But doesn't work. I usually stay FAR away from dictionaries, even after two years of coding, which is now biting me in the ass.

Comment: What is the expected output, really? A dict?

Comment: @Jan Yes, a dictionary, where the first index of the tuple is mapped to an integer, and the second index is mapped to an n-hot encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo (if I understood your question correctly) a very good use-case for a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

corp = [('h','somename'), 
        ('h','someothername'),
        ('a','awholeothername'),
        ('a','name again'),
       ]

mapping = defaultdict(lambda: -1)
mapping['h'] = 1
mapping['a'] = 0

result = [(mapping[key], value) for key, value in corp]
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
[(1, 'somename'), (1, 'someothername'), (0, 'awholeothername'), (0, 'name again')]
```

This has the advantage that you can have anything at all on the first position of your tuples (it will yield a `-1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.items()` to iterate over the keys and the values of dictionaries:

```
data = {'nationality': {} , 'name': {}}

for x, y in data.items():
    if x == 'h':
       corp[x] = 1  # If you want to actually edit the value, you have to do it this way.
    corp[x] = 0
```

Also, pay attention to the fact that you should use one `=` to do assignments.

---

To edit a list, find the index you want to change and use it in the assignment:

```
for i, value in enumerate(corp):
    x, y = value
    if x == 'h':
       corp[i][0] = 1
    corp[i][0] = 0
```